# firestore get data() not resolving the nested arrays

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

Running a nodejs code like

```
const snapshot = await db.collection('matches').where('series', '==', 'Series-2').get();
  snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.data());
  });
```

Its returning me data like

```
{
  inns: [
    {
      balls: [Array],
      ballers: [Array],
      bats: [Array],
      isDeclared: false
    },
    {
      bats: [Array],
      balls: [Array],
      isDeclared: false,
      ballers: [Array]
    },
    {
      bats: [Array],
      ballers: [Array],
      balls: [Array],
      isDeclared: false
    },
    {
      bats: [Array],
      ballers: [Array],
      isDeclared: false,
      balls: [Array]
    }
  ],
  id: 'jgvjbvwF',
  series: 'Series-2',
}
```

How can I get the full data i.e. instead of balls: [Array], it should be

```
balls: [
  { id: 1, runs: 0 },
  { id: 2, runs 1 },
  ...
]
```

Comment: What you mean by object ?

Comment: @Ashish question updated.

Comment: according to your posted data it's for only single doc. So you want to balls array from it

Comment: any example code?

Comment: See i posted the code for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting full array of docs. So you want to extract all balls array from it.
This is example code for understand.

Suppose, if we're taking doc1 as our example.

So code will be :

```
let doc1 = snapshot[0].data().inns;

doc1.forEach((in)=> {
    console.log(in.balls);
});
```

According to above code you can retrieve the all balls array from innings array

Comment: thanks, unfortunately I have large number of data and looks like to re-create a full json object is quite a complex thing :S

Comment: @coure2011 yes that's quite problamatic, but according to you're data you need to follow that procedure